How to Restrict Direct Modifications to main Branch for Specific Users in a Private GitHub Repo
In my private GitHub repository, I want to prevent certain users from directly modifying the main branch, while still allowing them to create pull requests. What is the best way to configure branch protection rules or permissions to achieve this and what other similar settings are advisable (prevent deletions etc.)?
As the repository owner, I still want the ability to push directly to the main branch.
I (think I) understand that I need to create a new branch ruleset for this purpose, but I’m unfamiliar with some of the options available in the ruleset configuration. Could you provide guidance on the key settings I should consider?
Also, is there an easier way to prevent specific users from doing any changes (i.e. make that read-only users)?
